# How can I hide my Gmail profile picture from contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-account, profile-picture

For the last few weeks, I have started seeing people's Gmail profile pictures in my contacts list or when I call them.

[image: Sample profile picture]

I don't want any callers (whether in my contacts or not) to see my profile photo. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no way. If you don't want people you interact with to see a specific identifying picture, you can change your Google Account's profile picture to something you don't mind sharing.

---

As of November 5, 2023, according to [Change your Gmail profile picture](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/35529?hl=en) from the Gmail Help Center,

> Your Gmail profile picture is the same as your Google Account picture.

According to [Control what others see about you across Google services](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6304920?hl=en) from the Google Accounts Help Center

> The following info might be shown to people you contact or share with:
>
> - Your name
> - Nickname
> - Profile picture
> - Cover photo
> - Your Google Account email

Manage your personal info and control who can see it when you use your main Google Account profile across Google services: **[Google Account > About me](https://myaccount.google.com/profile)**